# how to click Background and something should happend?

Tags: android, layout

I want to click the Background of a layout (not clicking anywhere, for example in the top right) and then reproduce a sound, can i put an empty View and put an On Click to that? I think is not possible.
If is possible, there is a better way? 
I want to put some invisible "buttons" at the Background because I will put an image Background with shapes, that's why It couldn't be anywhere.
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Look into [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) You can draw your shapes to it and also get x, y coords of screen touches.

Comment: Yes just put an empty `View` there. There is no other, or better solution. You could also just put a click listener on the root `View` of your layout.

Comment: I agree with @XaverKapeller, just attach a click listener to the root View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a button on the right corner and apply an empty or simply transparent image as icon button.
In this way, you can choose a different behavior for each screen position.